# What is the correct format string to parse "04.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100" with strptime()?

Tags: python, timestamp, strptime

I am trying to convert a weird format string timestamp to a datetime. This is what it looks like:

`04.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100`

I am trying something like this, but it's not matching. I think I am just missing the expression for that GMT offset at the end.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('04.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100','%d.%m.%Y HH:MM.SS.sss')
```

Of course it spits out the format error

```
ValueError: time data '04.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y HH:MM.SS.sss'
```

What is the format string I need to use here?

Comment: Your format string doesn't have anything that matches the timezone `GMT+0100`

Comment: And `HH:MM:SS.sss` should be `%h:%M:%s.000`

Comment: what if .000 has different value like 001 or 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need format operators for the time, not `HH:MM:SS`, and you need a format operator for the timezone. The operator for a timezone offset is `%z`.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('04.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100','%d.%m.%Y %h:%M:%s.%f GMT%z')
```

Comment: Is it correct to denote milisecons as %f ?

Comment: Also what does the %z denote?

Comment: Found this online: 
%f Microsecond as a decimal number, zero added on the left. 000000 – 999999

%z UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM.

Comment: Yes, `%f` will accept shorter than 6 digits. I answered the second question in the text.

Comment: See the notes: **When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right.**

Answer (score 2):

Use `%Z%z` to match the timezone. You were using some weird format for matching the time, `%H:%M:%S.%f` should be appropriate for that

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('04.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100','%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z%z')
# Outputs: datetime.datetime(2003, 5, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600), 'GMT'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('04.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100','%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f GMT%z')
```